# Run C++ program like a command from the terminal

Tags: command-line, programming

Hi,

I've created a small program in C++ I would like to run like a command from the terminal. With that I mean that I can open the program from and in the terminal (as it is a console application) regardless of which directory I'm in, without having to specify the path to the program. I know how to arrange it so that I would only have to type /program_name, but I'm interested in how the above would work.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Put the compiled executable in a directory that's on your `PATH`: see [How to run a program without typing the full path?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/104662/how-to-run-a-program-without-typing-the-full-path?)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks, I didn't find that thread on my searches, sorry

Comment: If the program is just for you, put it in `~/bin/program_name`. Then you can run it from anywhere via `program_name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either copy your executable to some folder in your `$PATH` (if you compiled your app statically) to see what is in your `$PATH` type:

```
echo $PATH
```

/usr/local/bin is probably the best choice. So copy it there by:

```
sudo cp yourexe /usr/local/bin
```

Or you can add additional directory to your `PATH`. You can do this by putting:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/some/folder
```

in your `~/.profile` file. Read more about it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path). You will probably need to logout after doing this.